# Send variables to server using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am hosting a personal website that uses p5.js. The problem is I need to send the variables to the server so that whenever I access the website it saves my data. Lets just call the variable that i want to save "test". Test's value is 3, and I want it to stay at 3 next time I access it. And I can change test's value to 5, but its value stays 0 when I refresh the page
(int test = 0)
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You should look at [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/)

Comment: Of course. It's just another javascript library like p5js. All it does is store variables for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send variables to the server to do this. You could just use cookies. Googling something like "JavaScript cookies" will give you a ton of results. I personally use [this library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), but you can easily write your own code that saves and loads cookies (in fact, if you don't really understands how cookies work, this is a good way to learn!).

The only reason you'd need to send something to the server is if you needed the values to persists for a user between different computers. This would require a login of some kind (not to mention code running on a server), and is a lot more work than just using a cookie. But if you really need to go this route, googling something like "JavaScript post" or "JavaScript ajax" will return a bunch of promising results. Of course, what you do with that information on the server is an entire project in itself.

Comment: @SlimeEnergy What do you need to install? The library I mentioned is simply a JavaScript library. You don't really install it. You just reference it on the page exactly like you would any other JavaScript library. But you don't even need to use a library. Just write and read the cookie directly yourself if you don't want to use a library for such a simple task. Please try something and try to ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: @SlimeEnergy Like I said, that's a much broader question. You don't really use cookies that way. If you want to save something between computers, you're going to have to create a server and store information in a database using login (and probably password) information. This is a huge and complicated topic, but I suggest googling something like "basic server side programming" for a bunch of information. Good luck.